# .htaccess redirect to start.php when querystring is empty

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need a redirect to start.php when theres yet no query string set..
I tried the following, without really knowing what the rexex does.

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$  #is there the equal operator = ''? 
 RewriteRule ^ /start.php/? [L]
 </IfModule>
 # END WordPress
```

Thanks for any help 
greetings form the cold, braoh!

peachio

Answer (score 2):

Your regex will match any text.  If you want it to match an empty string, use `^$`.